# How to add a margin or padding only for first and last thumbnails

Tags: android

I have a list of images with textviews. Below is the xml file for that view. But when I add images to this first image clipped off and the and the left screen of the phone. Also same thing happen to last image and right part of it clipped off .I tried to adding margin. But it applies for all the images. Then the middle images has more gap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
     android:paddingRight="3dp"
      android:paddingTop="6dp"
      android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
     android:background="#FFFFFFFF">  

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="55dp" 
        android:layout_height="95dp" 

        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />  


    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/title" 
        android:background="#90202020"      
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"

        android:text="1" >  

    </TextView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Below is the left side screenshot.

Comment: can you put image of how you want it and how it is showing now?

Comment: I added the left pat screenshot.Between first image and phone screen ,there is little gap.I neet to increase the gap.how to d othis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some margin/padding on the parent view (the one containing the list of images).